# A ball released from a certain height falls 5m in 1 sec; in 4 sec, it falls through..?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, free-fall

> A ball released from a certain height falls 5m in 1 second; in 4 seconds, it falls through...? Take $g=10m/s^2$

Answer : 80m

> My attempt: Since the body is released from a certain height, $u=0$
>
> Therefore, $H=(0.5)gt^2$
>
> In 4 seconds, displacement of the particle from the point of release =
>   $(0.5)g(4)^2$ =80m

Now, I don't understand what is the requirement of the first information that the ball falls 5metres in one second. Am I missing something or the information is not required at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem probably is illustratory. It's trying to show how constant acceleration motion gives you $t^2$ variation for the displacement. The displacement undergone in $4$ seconds is $16$ times the displacement undergone in $1$ second. (Beginners' intuition would suggest $4$ times.)

Comment: Random downvotes on this website make me laugh so much.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem there is superfluous information here. Just knowing the ball falls 5 meters in one second is enough to compute the drop height after 4 seconds.

It's possible the key here is that the extra piece of information tells us that air drag can be neglected (otherwise the ball would have fallen less than 5 m in a second, given g=10m/s$^2$).